# how to print Open layer map in pdf

Tags: php, pdf, jspdf

I have added open layer map with multiple layers and multiple shapes in php.
While exporting to PDF mutltiple layers are exporting with their specific button.
I am attaching screenshot for reference how it is printing in php page.

As shown in image same thing required in pdf [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJXuQ.jpg)

In pdf it is printing only 1 layer

Comment: How do you export to PDF?

Comment: By using jspdf and html2pdf